# I'm getting an error like "This version of dbt is not supported with the 'dbt_utils' package." PS: I'm using mac m1

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to run one of the models in dbt core but when I execute, I get this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jRt8.png)

This is my packages.yml file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN8nk.png)

Someone please help me resolve this issue. TIA.

I executed dbt deps as well

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vsRq.png)

I'm still getting the same error. Someone please help me resolve this issue. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You're running an old version of `dbt-core`. Try upgrading it with `pip`, it should match the requirements of `dbt-utils`.

```
pip install -U dbt-core
```